# How to pass a pointer argument to a function without knowing the size to be allocated for that pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I know this question is very noob. I am trying to understand how the pointer thing works. I studied basics of C but still did not understand this.

Given this piece of function:

```
+ (void)nv21ToRgbWithWidth:(unsigned int)width height:(unsigned int)height yuyv:(unsigned char *)yuyv rgb:(unsigned char *)rgb
{
    const int nv_start = width * height ;
    UInt32 i, j, index = 0, rgb_index = 0;
    UInt8 y, u, v;
    int r, g, b, nv_index = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <  height ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j ++){
            //nv_index = (rgb_index / 2 - width / 2 * ((i + 1) / 2)) * 2;
            nv_index = i / 2  * width + j - j % 2;

            y = yuyv[rgb_index];
            u = yuyv[nv_start + nv_index ];
            v = yuyv[nv_start + nv_index + 1];


            r = y + (140 * (v-128))/100;  //r
            g = y - (34 * (u-128))/100 - (71 * (v-128))/100; //g
            b = y + (177 * (u-128))/100; //b

            if(r > 255)   r = 255;
            if(g > 255)   g = 255;
            if(b > 255)   b = 255;
            if(r < 0)     r = 0;
            if(g < 0)     g = 0;
            if(b < 0)     b = 0;

            index = rgb_index % width + (height - i - 1) * width;
            rgb[index * 3+0] = b;
            rgb[index * 3+1] = g;
            rgb[index * 3+2] = r;
            rgb_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

How am I suppose to know how the `unsigned char *` for `rgb` should be initialized before passing in to the function?

I tried calling the function like this:

```
unsigned char *rgb = NULL;

[MyClass nv21ToRgbWithWidth:imageWidth height:imageHeight yuyv:yuyvValues rgb:rgb];
```

But the the program crashes on this line:

```
rgb[index * 3+0] = b;
```

I see `rgb` was initialized with NULL, so you can't assign values. So, I thought of initializing an array and pass it to pointer rgb like this:

```
unsigned char rgbArr[10000];
unsigned char *rgb = rgbArr;
```

but the function still crashes. I really don't know how should I pass the `rgb` parameter in this function. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected size in bytes seems to be at least `height*width*3`; it might be that allocating such an array as a local variable (as you do with `unsigned char rgbArr[10000]`)  exceeds a stack limit; The program likely crashes in such a case. I'd try to use the heap instead:

```
unsigned char* rgb = malloc(imageHeight*imageWidth*3);
[MyClass nv21ToRgbWithWidth:imageWidth height:imageHeight yuyv:yuyvValues rgb:rgb];
...
free(rgb);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what the malloc(), calloc(), realloc() and free() functions are for. Don't forget to use the free() function to prevent memory leaks... I hope that helps.